# how to initialize istream by user input on keyboard?

Tags: c++

now I have a class named Game(istream&). 
when i wanna build an object of Game, I need an istream that should be user input. such as user type "abcdefg", the istream should be "abcdefg".

but I don't find a way to initilize the istream by user input, could you help me? thx.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about input redirection?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::istringstream`.

```
std::string input = "abcdefg";
std::istringstream istr(input);
Game g(istr);
```